# Can we not makes changes to specific fields in the value for a given Key in COuchbase Java API?

Tags: memcached, couchdb, couchbase

I have this schema

```
{"type": "record",
"name": "Member",
"fields": [
{"name": "name", "type": ["string", "null"] },
{"name": "skill", "type": ["string" , "null"]}
]}
```

Now I have initially inserted some data into couchbase for say 3 members

```
KEY VALUE 
id  name skill
1   abc  java
2   pqr  cookin
3   xyz  fishing
```

So suppose If now only `name` changes for `id=3` ... Can I do that in couchbase .. As, I hve observed that couchbase overwrites the `skill` with `NULL` if it is not mentioned .. i.e. 
if `id=3` changes `name` to def

I get output as

```
id  name skill
3   def  null
```

whereas I want the skill to be the same ...

Comment: No. Unless the SDK/driver you use does that, the entire document is written each time. It's not updating an existing document.

Comment: What client library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Here http://cnx.org/content/m43483/latest/ I have an example which illustrates how to experiment with storing JSON documents in a couchDB. For updating you have to read the whole document, change the value you want and then write everything back.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is something called "Partial Updates", you **can** do it (despite the information from other posters here) just that it's not built into CouchDB (as of 1.3) so you have to do a bit of setup by adding an update handler.

See here for more info: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Partial_Updates